# QPixmap not displaying on the dialog in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5

I am trying to display a pixmap onto a window but for some reason it would not display this time (I have done it before but cannot pinpoint where I went wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out when I displayed the pixmap before I instantiated in a ResizeEvent rather in the Widgets constructor.

```cpp
pixRecieve=QPixmap(size());
  pixRecieve.fill();
```

But this time I did it in the constructor since I do not need a ResizeEvent in this widget.

In order to construct the QPixMap you need to input the size of the PixMap to the constructor.

The `size()` function holds the current size of the window so that the Pixmap can fill the whole window.